We have been encountering persistent 500 Internal Server Errors while using the Google Drive API
We have been encountering persistent 500 Internal Server Errors while using the Google Drive API. Despite implementing backoff functionality, these errors have been occurring frequently over the past few days, which was not the case previously. Any insights or solutions you could provide would be greatly appreciated.
We are syncing the Google Drive files data for all domain users into our database using the Google Drive API. Initially, the process starts without any issues, but after a few minutes, we start receiving 500 Internal Server Errors frequently. Although we have implemented backoff functionality, we are still encountering too many 500 errors. Currently, it takes the entire day to sync all the data, whereas a few days ago, we were able to complete the sync within a few minutes. We are unsure why this is happening on Google's side.
func GetFileList(userId string, nextPageToken string, driveId string, driveService *drive.Service, b *backoff.ExponentialBackOff) (*drive.FileList, error) {
    var fileList *drive.FileList
    isTokenRefresh := false
    b.Reset()
    retryable := func() error {
        //nextPageToken := pageToken
        //for nextPageToken != "" {
        var gError *googleapi.Error
        service := driveService.Files.List().Fields("*").PageSize(1000).Fields("*").OrderBy("folder")
        if nextPageToken != "abc" {
            service = service.PageToken(nextPageToken)
        }
        if driveId != "" {
            service = service.DriveId(driveId).Corpora("drive").SupportsAllDrives(true).IncludeItemsFromAllDrives(true)
        }
        if driveId == "" {
            service = service.Q("'me' in owners")
        }
        fileListAPI, err1 := service.Do()
        if err1 != nil {
            fmt.Println("GetFileList inner err", err1.Error(), ":*******")
            if strings.Contains(err1.Error(), "www.googleapis.com") || strings.Contains(err1.Error(), "www.google.com") || strings.Contains(err1.Error(), "<!DOCTYPE") {
                fmt.Println("new google error", err1)
                if strings.Contains(err1.Error(), "oauth2") {
                    fmt.Println("new google Unauthorized error", err1)
                    return nil
                }
                return errors.New(err1.Error())
            }
            if errors.As(err1, &gError) {
                gError.Wrap(err1)
                fmt.Println("gError.Message", gError.Message, gError.Code)
                if gError.Code == 401 && gError.Message == "Invalid Credentials" {
                    fmt.Println("Invalid Credentials", gError)
                    var e error
                    e, driveService = GetAuthorizedDriveClient(userId)
                    if e != nil {
                        fmt.Println("refreshToken error", e)
                    }
                    isTokenRefresh = true
                    if isTokenRefresh {
                        return nil
                    }
                    return errors.New(gError.Message)
                }
                if gError.Code == 500 || gError.Code == 502 || gError.Code == 503 || gError.Code == 504 || gError.Code == 429 {
                    return errors.New(gError.Message)
                }
                if gError.Errors != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("erroriferr: %v", gError)
                    //fmt.Println("err", gError)
                    if gError.Code == 500 || gError.Code == 502 || gError.Code == 503 || gError.Code == 504 || gError.Code == 429 {
                        return errors.New("server error")
                    }
                    if len(gError.Errors) != 0 && (gError.Errors[0].Message == "Invalid Credentials" || gError.Message == "Invalid Credentials" || gError.Message == "authError" || gError.Message == "The request is missing a valid API key.") {
                        return errors.New(gError.Message)
                    }
                    if len(gError.Errors) > 0 && gError.Errors[0].Reason == "userRateLimitExceeded" || gError.Errors[0].Reason == "rateLimitExceeded" {
                        return errors.New(gError.Message)
                    }
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
        fileList = fileListAPI

        return nil
    }
    notify := func(err error, t time.Duration) {
        log.Warnf("Failed to HTTP GET GetFileList. retrying in %s seconds. err: %s", t, err)
    }
    err := backoff.RetryNotify(retryable, b, notify)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error after retrying: %v", err)
    }
    return fileList, nil
}


Please edit your question and include [example]

@LindaLawton-DaImTo edited

To address different types of error while using the Google API's in your case the Drive API there is a page that show some information and recommendation in how yo handle different type of code errors in your code.
The following article: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/handle-errors#5xx-errors
I understand that you have already implemented backoff, have you tried to increase the amount of time for the retrys?
Also you can check here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/troubleshoot-api-errors and see if there is not an issue tracker realted to Drive or Drive API that could be the reason of the 500 code error messages.
If none of the previous suggestions works for you, you should open a ticket with the Google Workspace Support with you Super Admin user of your organization to get a case number and further investigate the issue with the product team.
Here is the steps to open a ticket with support: https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en&sjid=5226130840317534831-NC
On the product when you open the ticket you should put the Drive option.
